# Google Chrome Extension - stop browser navigation

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I stop browser navigation from a Google Chrome extension?

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    alert("webRequest.onBeforeRequest -- Navigation blocked");
    return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("bing.com") != -1};
}, null, ["blocking"]);
```

The above code doesn't work!

Comment: In Mozilla Firefox there is getWebNavigation().stop(3);