# Stopping navigation in Chrome (google chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My goal: When I click a link, stop all requests **and** the browser from navigating to that link. Essentially, if i clicked the link http://tabbit.org/about, nothing would happen. no requests, no navigation, nothing.

I am successfull in stopping the requests with "onBeforeRequest" listener, but the browser still tries to navigate to the href's value, giving me a page that says *"This webpage was blocked by an extension"*

What I have tried

```
var navigate = true;
var url = "http://tabbit.org/about"

/*
 * Will prevent headers from being sent. Browser will still
 * try to navigate to the clicked link, though.
 */
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        navigate = false;
        return {cancel: true} ;
    },
    // filters
    {urls: [url]},

     ["blocking"]
  );


// Somewhere in here is where I think navigation needs to be stopped.
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if (navigate == false) {
            return false; // doesn't work.
            //return {cancel: true}; // doesn't work.
        };  
    },
    {urls: [url]},
    ["blocking"]
)
```

I didn't want to use a content script because I want do this for forms as well.
So basically if an http request is made to a certain URL, GET or POST, i'd like for nothing to happen.

I have browsed  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505295/google-chrome-extension-stop-browser-navigation) (and web) for a solution, but no dice.

Comment: Did you try redirecting to a 204 page in `onBeforeRequest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following in your callback for `onBeforeRequest`:

```
    return {redirectUrl: 'http://google.com/gen_204'};
```

Comment: Many thanks. Didn't think of this. The actual key is "redirectUrl", though. (might wanna edit the answer to fix that). thanka again.